# How to add a language on a Galaxy S7 Edge without root?

Tags: languages, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I have a Galaxy S7 and it is locked so I can't add new languages. Can someone tell me if this is possible without root?

Comment: Pointer: [related questions with answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[languages]+install+answers%3A1). Are you asking for a keyboard language, or a system language?

Comment: It should be system language i guess.

Comment: Even though your device is locked, you can add languages that comes with TouchWiz UI. I am not sure for input language or total language change from English to your choice you are asking but I think this article on [Samsung Galaxy S7 & S7 Edge tips](http://technosamigos.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-tips-and-tricks/) will help you. There, you need to scroll till the bottom.

Comment: When you say "add a language" do you mean select a language that's already available from the dropdown, or add a new language?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without root like this

- Download [MoreLocale2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale)
- Run:

  ```
  adb shell pm grant jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
  ```
- Change the device's language from **MoreLocale** app